# retrieving max records from sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been toiling with this for a while now. so decided to ask and get some help.

I have two tables as such:

```
tblTrans: (DocNumber field is always unique)

DocNumber       TransDate      userId
66-FF-GHIP      03-05-08       someUser
55-RT-JHTP      03-09-09       someOtherUser
77-AF-KPWT      05-08-09       userId1
09-IO-TEAG      04-08-09       thisUser


tblTransDet: (productIdCode field + DocNumber fields are always unique)
DocNumber       ProductIdCode      TransStatus   
66-FF-GHIP      4124               Approved
66-FF-GHIP      2124               Pending
66-FF-GHIP      2340               Approved
77-AF-KPWT      4124               Approved
55-RT-JHTP      4124               Pending
09-IO-TEAG      2124               Pending
```

As you can see. ProductIdCode 4124 is repeating multiple times in tblTransDet but combination of productIdCode and DocNumber is always unique.

How Can i retrieve docnumber and productID ...based on the docNumber that has highest transDate.

So In this example. the final result would be

```
77-AF-KPWT    4124
09-IO-TEAG    2124
66-FF-GHIP    2340
```

I'd change the tablestrcuture if i could :(

Comment: I don't get it - how do you get ProductID 2340 for Doc# 66-FF-GHIP based on the date? There doesn't seem to be any relationship...

Comment: because i am getting all the productId's from that table. and since 2340 is unique...it should show up. if there were TWO instances of 2340 then the one with max transaction date would show up

Comment: I don't get it either. Perhaps you should show us some DDL of your two tables.

Comment: Still don't get it - if you get the MAX date for a DocNumber in table 1 - you will have one DocNumber + a date - how to use that Docnumber to select a single record out of table2?

Comment: Probably you have ProductIDCode in the first table instead of DocNumber, do you?

Comment: there is no productIDCode in first table. I am trying to select unique combination of productID and DocNumber from the second table. If data is NOT unique then it should be made unique based on which of the two doc number have highest date. Mbe my output data in question is wrong. i will correct it

Comment: OK - I'm starting to get  it - you want a single productID returned + the corresponding Docnumber with the highest transaction date

Answer (score 1):

Use a corelated subquery - this is untested:

```
SELECT
   d.DocNumber, d.ProductId, t.TransDate
FROM
   tblTransDet d, tblTrans t
WHERE
   d.DocNumber = t.DocNumber
AND
   t.TransDate = (SELECT MAX( TransDate) FROM tblTrans
                   WHERE DocNumber = d.DocNumber)
```

Comment: @Neil, I think you should reread the question. With the data the OP has given, It is not possible.

Comment: this brings duplicates as well and not single row of data for productID and documentnumber. In this case this would bring all documentnumbers that productID 4124 is related to. rather than bringing just "77-AF-KPWT    4124" since that documnet number has highest date

Answer (score 0):

you could use a subquery

```
WHERE Detail.Date = (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM TransDet)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  d.DocNumber, d.ProductId, t.TransDate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.DocNumber, d.ProductId ORDER BY TransDate DESC) AS rn
        FROM   tblTransDet d, tblTrans t
        WHERE  t.DocNumber = d.DocNumber
        )
WHERE rn = 1
```